# Using Cgroups to limit cpu usage

Tags: linux, performance, cpu-usage, cgroups

I am trying to use cgroups in order to limit the CPU usage. I am using this guide 
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpu_and_memory-use_case.html

My /etc/cgconfig.conf file is the following

```
mount {
cpu     = /mnt/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct;
cpuacct = /mnt/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct;
}

group wheel {
    cpu {
            cpu.shares="800";
    }
    cpuacct {
            cpuacct.usage="0";
    }
}
 group test1 {
    cpu {
            cpu.shares="200";
    }
    cpuacct {
            cpuacct.usage="0";
    }
}
```

My cgrules.conf is the following

```
@wheel cpu,cpuacct wheel
@test1 cpu,cpuacct test1
```

Althouth when I try to run:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1024k
```

I see that the cpu usage in 100% for the users belong to group wheel and test1

I have checked the services with 
   service cgconfig status
and is up

```
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/cgconfig.service; disabled)
Active: active (exited) since Mon 2015-03-02 17:29:19 EET; 7min ago
Process: 1240 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/cgclear -l /etc/cgconfig.conf -e   (code=exited, status=3)
Process: 56536 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf -s         1664 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 56536 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you add output of `top` command when you're running `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1024k`?

Comment: `cgroup` shares will only limit CPU resources *when there is competition for them*. If, in your example, `test1` wants CPU resources, and `wheel` is not using any, then there is no competition, and `test1` can have whatever it wants. If both are demanding resources, then you should see the share-based limiting taking affect.

Comment: Hello the output is the following:

`
  `PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND `                                    
`51535 user1    20   0  108956   1680    556 R 100.0  0.0   0:27.74 dd`                                          
`51557 user2   20   0  108956   1676    552 R 100.0  0.0   0:23.57 dd`
user1 belongs to wheel group and user2 to test1 group

Comment: @twalberg Thank you very much for your answer. I ran the `dd` commant for both users at the same time. I put also above the result of the top command. Do you believe that I should try with another command?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

cpu cgroup is work conserving, ie. a task would not be stopped from using cpu if there is no competition. If you want to put a hard limit on amount of cpu a task can use, try setting `cpu.cfs_quota_us` and `cpu.cfs_period_us`.

Look at the documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpu.html).

Comment: RedHat documentation link is 404, found this however: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55914709/130638

Comment: `cgroups` version 2 use `cpu.max` instead of `cpu.cfs_` (though cgroups man page says "Although  cgroups  v2  is intended as a replacement for cgroups v1, the
       older system continues to exist (and for compatibility reasons  is  un‐
       likely  to be removed).".)